# Update an entity with relationships to another entity in spring

Tags: json, spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have two entities, `Offre` and `OffreCompetence` and a relation between them as following :

```
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="offre",cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
        private Collection<OffreCompetence> offreCompetences;
```

So each `Offre` entity has many `OffreCompetence` entities.

Let's assume I have an 'Offre' as following :

```
    {
        "codeOffre": 144,
        "titre": "Testable 999",
          "offreCompetences": [
    {
      "codeOffreCompetence": 93,
      "niveauRequis": "77",
      "competence": {
        "codeCompetence": 17,
        "titre": "Administrateur Mainframe IBM",
        "activated": true
      }
    },
    {
      "codeOffreCompetence": 94,
      "niveauRequis": "88",
      "competence": {
        "codeCompetence": 18,
        "titre": "Administrateur Autres Systèmes",
        "activated": true
      }
    },
    {
      "codeOffreCompetence": 95,
      "niveauRequis": "99",
      "competence": {
        "codeCompetence": 19,
        "titre": "Concepteur UML, Merise, ...",
        "activated": true
      }
    },
    {
      "codeOffreCompetence": 96,
      "niveauRequis": "88",
      "competence": {
        "codeCompetence": 18,
        "titre": "Administrateur Autres Systèmes",
        "activated": true
      }
    },
    {
      "codeOffreCompetence": 97,
      "niveauRequis": "99",
      "competence": {
        "codeCompetence": 17,
        "titre": "Administrateur Mainframe IBM",
        "activated": true
      }
    }
  ],
        "ville": {
          "codeVille": 2
        },
        "typeContrat": {
          "codeTypeContrat": 3
        }
      }
```

Then I want to update this `Offre`, so I call a put method which takes an 'Offre' as a param, then this method will call the business code to update this 'Offre', and this is the method that updates this entity :

```
public Offre updateOffre(Offre offre) {

    for(OffreCompetence offreCompetence : offre.getOffreCompetences()) {
        offreCompetence.setOffre(offre);
    }
    return offreRepository.saveAndFlush(offre);
}
```

So I'll send this new json where I deleted some 'OffreCompetence' relationships and I added a new one :

```
{
    "codeOffre": 144,
    "titre": "Testable 999",
    "offreCompetences": [
      {
        "codeOffreCompetence": 96,
        "niveauRequis": "88",
        "competence": {
          "codeCompetence": 18
        }
      },
      {
        "niveauRequis": "5",
        "competence": {
          "codeCompetence": 17
        }
      }
    ],
    "ville": {
      "codeVille": 2
    },
    "typeContrat": {
      "codeTypeContrat": 3
    }
  }
```

The problem here is that it adds these two relationships as new ones to the old ones, as you can see I've deleted one and updated one and removed one, so the updated `Offre` should only contain the relationships I've sent.

I've thought about before setting the new relationships to delete the old one using a service method that searches for all relationships with `Offre` and delete them then add the ones I've sent with the `Offre` object, but I want this to be done automatically.

Any suggestion ?

Thanks is advance.

## Edit :

it seems that adding new relationships and updating them is working but deleting it doesn't work.

Comment: did you try hibernate merge?

Answer (score 0):

The best I could get given a tree of detached objects (your JSON `Offre` and `OffreCompetence` was the following. My case was 2 entities, `Order` and `OrderLine`, mapped the same way you did.

Order.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ORDERS")
public class Order implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "ORDER_ID")
    private Long id;

    // ... basic attributes

    // same mapping as in your use case
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "order", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<OrderLine> orderLines;

    /* getters and setters */

}
```

OrderLine.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ORDER_LINES")
public class OrderLine implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "ORDER_LINE_ID")
    private Long id;

    // ... basic attributes

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ORDER_ID")
    private Order order;

    /* getters and setters */

    /* equals and hashCode */

}
```

Persisting the root node and its children was done like this:

```
@Override
public Order findWithReference(String reference) {
    List<Order> list = em.createQuery("SELECT o FROM Order o WHERE o.reference = :reference")
            .setParameter("reference", reference).getResultList();
    if (list.isEmpty()) {
        return null;
    } else if (list.size() == 1) {
        return list.get(0);
    } else {
        throw new IllegalStateException(String.format("The reference '%s' should uniquely identify an order.", reference));
    }
}

@Override
public Order save(Order order) {
    Order managed = findWithReference(order.getReference());
    if (managed == null) {
        em.persist(order);
        return order;
    } else {
        // remove obsolete children and children existing both in detached and managed entity
        for (Iterator<OrderLine> iter = managed.getOrderLines().iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
            OrderLine managedOrderLine = iter.next();
            if (!order.getOrderLines().contains(managedOrderLine)) {
                iter.remove();
                em.remove(managedOrderLine);
            } else {
                order.getOrderLines().remove(managedOrderLine);
            }
        }
        order.setId(managed.getId());
        return em.merge(order);
    }
}
```

The trick for the merge to give satisfactory results is to remove obsolete children from the managed entity and already existing children from the detached instance. To match the children, I implemented `equals` and `hashCode` in `OrderLine` for a not so ugly method overall.